# How do I configure Drupal so that is not in a subdirectory?

Tags: cpanel, drupal, subdirectory, folder

I loaded Drupal folder into **public_html**. All works fine. The site opens correctly, but only when I give full address including folder as `IP:80/drupal`. How do I use only `IP:80` to access the website. I am using cPanel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. I need to edit public_html/.htaccess and put DirectoryIndex /drupal_installation_folder/index.php

Answer (score 0):

You can put everything in the drupal installation folder in public_html. If the index.php file is there, it will load as you expect it to.